# Getting image with json and show in listview

Tags: android, json, image, listview, show

I'm writing my biggest application and now I have written a json code which gets text from server and shows in list view. Until here everything is ok, but my problem is that I want to show image in my list too.

I have made some changes in my code to show image in list but I always get no image.

I have seen many answers but didn't work. If its possible to solve my problem with picaso lib please help me with that or any other things.

Here is my code:

**list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_view3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listrowbg"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:background="@drawable/newshead"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ico"
        android:background="@drawable/standinpic"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textColor="#fafafa"
        android:textDirection="ltr"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:singleLine="false"


        android:maxLines="3"

        android:maxLength="100"


        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:phoneNumber="false"

        android:text="Abadi - SohMj"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ico"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:background="@drawable/more"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ico"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtexe"
        android:textColor="#ffc53220"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Tab1 ( get news)**

```
public class tab1 extends ListFragment {


static final String url_all_products = "http://persiancoder.tk/rapnews/get_all_products.php";
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
final String TAG_RAPNEWS = "rapnews";
final String TAG_PID = "pid";
final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
final String TAG_PIC = "pic";
final String TAG_WRITER = "writer";

// JSON Node names

// products JSONArray
JSONArray rapnews = null;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
    final View rootView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   final ImageView vi =(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ico);







/**


    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try {




        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://persiancoder.tk/rapnews/get_all_products.php");
        //conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
        //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        String n = "";
        String a = "";
        String j = "";

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String pic = json.getString("pic");


           TAG_PIC = pic.toString();



        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        dlgAlert.setMessage("مشکلی نامعلوم پیش آمده!اینترنت خود را چک کنید");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("Unknown Problem!");
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("باشه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

    }

**/















    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Loading products in Background Thread

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */

    try {


        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading, Wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * getting All products from url
             */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        rapnews = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RAPNEWS);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                            JSONObject c = rapnews.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                            String pic = c.getString(TAG_PIC);





                                // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                           map.put(TAG_TITLE, name);
                    map.put(TAG_PIC, pic);




                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                Main.class);
                        // Closing all previous activities
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * *
             */
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                                TAG_TITLE,TAG_PIC},
                                new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.txttitle,R.id.ico}

                        );

                        setListAdapter(adapter);

                    }
                });

            }









                // Declaring Your View and Variables





            }









        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {

        final AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dlgAlert.setMessage("لطفا اینترنت خودرا چک کنید! یا ممکن است سرور از دسترس خارج شده باشد ، برای اخبار اپدیت و مشکلات به ویکی رپ مراجعه کنید!");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("Connection Error!");
        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("باشه گرفتم", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity() , Main.class));
            }
        });

        dlgAlert.create().show();
    }
































    return v;

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Loading, Please Wait...",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String pid = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
            .toString();

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),Shownews.class);
    // sending pid to next activity
    in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

    // starting new activity and expecting some response back
    startActivity(in);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always good not to reinvent the wheel.
While loading image from URL there are many things that one has to keep in mind :

1. Loading in async task.
2. Caching of image. (For offline usage).
3. Loading image when needed.

The most efficient library I have used is **Universal Image Library**.
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It is pretty efficient and easy to use. You can find easy to follow sample here : 
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample